# Implementing a special CRC algorithm in Python using crcmod

Tags: python, crc

I'm trying to implement the "VÖV 04.05.1" CRC algorithm in python. This is used in data telegrams for public transport communication in Germany. The standard that describes the algorithm is behind a paywall and copyright protected, so I can't publish the original document here, but this is a summary:

Basically, it uses CRC-16 with the following generator polynomial:
G(x) = x^16 + x^14 + x^13 + x^11 + x^10 + x^9 + x^8 + x^6 + x^5 + x^1 + 1

The resulting bits then have to be inverted.

Currently I'm using the crcmod package for python to generate the CRC. The polynom is translated to `0x16f63` in HEX (at least I think so). This is my code:

```
import crcmod

#message from which the checksum is to be formed
msg = "00000000000000000000000010000000"

#crcmod parameters
crc16 = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x16f63, rev=True, initCrc=0x0000, xorOut=0x0000)

#interpret string as binary, convert to bytes, calculate CRC
crc_result = crc16(int(msg, 2).to_bytes((len(msg) + 7) // 8, 'big'))

#print result in BIN and HEX
print(bin(crc_result))
print(hex(crc_result))
```

The standard contains two examples for CRC calculation:

1. `00000000000000000000000000000001` must result in a CRC of `0x4c7d`
2. `00000000000000000000000010000000` must result in a CRC of `0x909c`

Despite fiddling around with the parameters, I don't get the correct results. Even with inverted bits. I appreciate any help!

Comment: shouldn't the polynomial go from x^0 to x^15? yours goes from x^0 to x^16 which is 17 elements

Comment: crcmod expects a polynomial with a degree of 8, 16, 24, 32 or 64. I think that the highest bit is omitted later in the process.

Comment: are the initial and xor values definitely 0? you could try iterating through all the options, as I see in crcmod's predefined table these values go from 0x0000 to 0xffff, and probably the rev can be also flipped to cover all the variables, that's around `8_589_934_592` calls, might take some time, but you can just run it and wait until someone has a better answer :)

Comment: Thank you, other init and xor values might have done the trick! Now I got correct results. As soon as I can confirm this with real world data, I will post the final code, so everyone can benefit from it.

Comment: You would need to provide another example with a different message length, in order to determine the initial value and final exclusive-or. Without that, there are 65,536 different combinations of those two parameters that will work for the two provided examples.

Comment: @GáborFekete For any initial value, you can compute the CRC and then exclusive-or the result with the desired CRC to get the final exclusive-or that would be needed. You only need to look at the 65,536 initial values to find all of the initial value/final xor combinations that will work.

Comment: so what was the final value then?

Comment: The values are: 0x16f63, rev=True, initCrc=0xFFFF, xorOut=0xFFFF. As of now, I can't confirm its correct. Next week I get some real world data with longer data telegrams and hashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don´t look to deep in the spec, it is confusing because of weird bit orders (info bytes are mirrored, but CRC bytes are not!). Simply concat the information bits in the received order to "msg" and run it aginst:

```
import crcmod
msg = "00000000000000000000000010000000"

#crcmod parameters
crc16 = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x16f63, rev=False, initCrc=0xFFFF, xorOut=0xFFFF)

#interpret string as binary, convert to bytes, calculate CRC
crc_result = crc16(int(msg, 2).to_bytes((len(msg) + 7) // 8, 'big'))

#print result in BIN and HEX
print(bin(crc_result))
print(hex(crc_result))
```

Result for msg = "00000000000000000000000000000001":

```
0b1001000010011100
0x909c
```

Result for msg = "00000000000000000000000010000000":

```
0b100110001111101
0x4c7d
```

More test data for verification can be found here: https://github.com/tlm-solutions/telegram-decoder/blob/master/data/valid_r09_16_telegrams.json

Comment: Thank you very much! Especially the test data is quite useful. With this, I hope that I can verify and generate valid telegrams.